# Search URL not including '/search' - Not redirecting correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a search bar partially working. However it seems that from my home page it does not redirect to my `products#index` page. When I search for a product I get the following url: `http://localhost:3000/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=intel` however if I change the url to look like the following: `http://localhost:3000/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=intel` this will work. My setup follows:

**SearchController**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.all(:conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"])
  end
end
```

**ProductsController.rb**

```
def index
    @products = Product.filter(params[:search], [:title])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end
```

**application.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_tag search_path, :class => 'navbar-form to-the-right', :method => 'get' do %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'span2', :placeholder => 'Search' %>
        <% end %>
      </form>
```

**Routes.rb**

```
  match '/search' => 'search#index'
```

I cannot seem to identify why this is not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your post i try this :

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def index
   @products = Product.filter(params[:title])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end
```

product.rb

```
 def self.filter (search_title)
  return scoped unless search_title.present?
    where(['title LIKE ?', "%#{search_title}%"])
 end
```

route.rb

```
match '/search' => 'products#index'
```

application.html

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :class => 'navbar-form to-the-right', :method => 'get' do %>
 <%= text_field_tag :title, params[:title], :class => 'span2', :placeholder => 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. But I believe the main problem is that is that the search bar does not work from the home controller. By I mean that if you search for something you it does not redirect. The imgur show exactly what I mean http://i.imgur.com/Gyu8eqB.png. You will notice that the url is `http://localhost:3000/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=intel+i5` this does not show no result. However if i do `http://localhost:3000/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=intel+i5` this works! for some reason it is not taking in the `search`

Comment: you need to know where you are and where you want to go. My code works i try it into one app.

Comment: The form can be used anywhere into your app with the route used, he will filter your index products view according to the title name you submit.

Comment: I am not saying that it should not work because I believe it should! I followed initially - http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form and that didn't seem to work but I will accept it because you gave a full explanation that will help someone in the near future. I have the exact same setup and am in the same situation. But not to worry

Comment: You know what better yet! I found the root of my problem. My search bar was encased within the following ` <form class="navbar-search pull-left"> </form>` I believe that for some reason this was the root of the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Your route does not provide a helper `search_path`. To enable that do this:

```
match '/search' => 'search#index', as: :search
```

Comment: Could this potentially be the cause